# Embed randomly named MP3

Tags: php, html, random, mp3

Here's my code:

```
<embed src="/sound/lowyourchicken.mp3" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>
```

I would like the src for the .mp3 to take in to account that there are many randomly named .mp3 files in the `/sound/` directory, and to choose one at random each time the page is opened. Any clues for me?

My server is PHP enabled but I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you please post it?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just HTML. You probably will need server-side code to pick a random file name and inject it into the HTML before it gets sent to the client.

Comment: if not possible in the html, can anyone point me towards some php with this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$files = glob("/path/to/directory/*.mp3");
$random = array_rand($files)
```

Then do this:

```
<embed src="<?php echo $random ?>" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>
```

Comment: when I put the php in the header and the embed in the body i end up with a weird white box on the page where the mp3 should be, and the source looks like this:
<embed src="random" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>

Comment: @John: I think @bpeterson76 was missing a `$` in the echo statement.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did try putting the $ in before random but it just changed the output from src="random" to src=""

I was putting the php in the head of the actual index.php html though, where should I be placing it?

Comment: Are you wrapping the top part in <?php   ....   ?> tags?  Php won't work without tags around it.

Comment: OK so I've moved the php from the head to the body to makes things clearer here, here's what it looks like:
`<?php
$files = glob("/sound/*.mp3");
$random = array_rand($files)
?>
<embed src="<?php echo $random ?>" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>
`

Comment: oh and source on the loaded page still looks like this:
'<embed src="" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>'

Answer (score 0):

array_rand returns what random index it chose, so you'll need to do this:

```
<embed src="<?php $files[ $random ] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
It will Work, I used original code found in answers and did some tweaking by adding `array($files)` in the `$random = array_rand();` variable statement

You will first need to put the PHP code in the body like this

```
<?php
$files = glob("assets/songs/SayYesToLove/*.mp3");
$random = array_rand(array($files));
?>
```

next add this just outside that php code in the body

```
<embed src="<?php echo $files[$random]; ?>" width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE">
</embed>
```

Please Notice the **echo** output in the src file. This will ensure it gets outputted to your page. Also don't forget to use the **;** at the end of **every** php variable statement as this can through some errors.