# Randomized music play via HTML javascript not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, background-music

What I'm trying to do is randomly generating background embed on each page load from 0-3 as shown below. This file is located in `body` section of `index.html`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var music = [],
index = 0;

music[0] = "<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music1.mp3"></embed>";
music[1] = "<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music2.mp3"></embed>";
music[2] = "<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music3.mp3"></embed>";
music[3] = "<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music4.mp3"></embed>";

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * music.length);
document.write(music[index]);
</script>
```

The issue is that the music does not play in any browser with the above script.

Comment: You either need to escape your quotes, or use single quotes. eg:`'<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music4.mp3"></embed>';`

Comment: You need to escape the quotes.
`music[0] = "<embed name=\"myMusic\" loop=\"false\" hidden=\"true\" src=\"music1.mp3\"></embed>";`

Comment: If you use double quotes on the outside, you need to use single quotes on the inside or vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Does it just not play?  For what it's worth, not all browsers support what you're trying to do anyway.

Comment: `how to get this working` is not a proper problem description, please add one.

Comment: You could use php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979639/embed-randomly-named-mp3-in-html

Comment: @ѺȐeallү I don't see a PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the valuable answers! :)

I got it working now. The problem was indeed the quotes i had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add slash before double quote like this :

```
music[0] = "<embed name=\"myMusic\" loop=\"false\" hidden=\"true\" src=\"music1.mp3\"></embed>";
```

Or replace double quote like this :

```
music[0] = '<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music1.mp3"></embed>';
```

Full code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var music = [],
index = 0;

music[0] = '<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music1.mp3"></embed>';
music[1] = '<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music2.mp3"></embed>';
music[2] = '<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music3.mp3"></embed>';
music[3] = '<embed name="myMusic" loop="false" hidden="true" src="music4.mp3"></embed>';

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * music.length);
document.write(music[index]);
</script>
```